# Spacing of fractions in TeX Gyre Pagella Math

Tags: math-mode, spacing, xetex, fractions, tex-gyre-math

Using `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` with `xelatex`, some objects like `\frac12` just seem way too large compared to the rest of the equations. Have a look:
[image: Ugly fractions in TeX Gyre Pagella Math]

In the first line, the numerator looks like it's floating away. The second line using a `\scriptstyle` size looks better, but the baseline is off. Finally, the exponent in the very last line also looks off. Here it seems like it's sitting way too low.

Do I have a weird impression of these things, or does this simply not look nice? Can I somehow fix it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
This is quite ugly:\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{
\( \displaystyle   \frac12 \int x = 0.5 \int x \)
} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{
\( \displaystyle {\scriptstyle \frac12} \int x = 0.5 \int x \)
} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{
\( \displaystyle   e^{\frac12 x+1} = e^{0.5 x+1} \)
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: May be tweaking some `\fontdimen`s by hand which are badly set in TeX Gyre Pagella Math? *Off Topic*: Is there a certain reason to use XeTeX rather than LuaTeX?

Comment: I can't see any particular misplacement. The effect is probably amplified by the smallness of the integral sign in TeX Gyre Pagella. Rather than `{\scriptstyle\frac{1}{2}}` you should use `\tfrac{1}{2}`

Comment: You cannot use `{\scriptstyle...}` inside `\displaystyle`. Use `\textstyle` instead this. This is natural that the math axis of `\scriptstyle` is differently positioned than in `\display/textstyle`. The space between 1 and fraction rule in displaystyle can be corrected by `\fontdimen8\textfont2` in normal math setting, but this is unicode-math which could be different (I don't know).